# JSON to Stacked DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-analysis

I've got a JSON file that looks like:

```
[

        {
        "id" : "abc",
        "mood" : "happy",
        "scores" : [
            10,
            15,
            20
            ]
        },
        {
        "id" : "def",
        "mood" : "happy",
        "scores" : [
            103,
            150,
            200
            ]
        },
        {
        "id" : "ghi",
        "mood" : "sad",
        "scores" : [
            1,
            15,
            20,
            45,
            600,
            1400
            ]
        },
        {
        "id" : "jkl",
        "mood" : "sad",
        "scores" : [
            10,
            100,
            1000,
            10000
            ]
        }

]
```

Which I'm trying to get into a stacked DataFrame that looks like:

```
    id    mood    score
0  abc    happy   10
1  abc    happy   15
2  abc    happy   20
3  def    happy   103
...
14 jkl    sad     10
15 jkl    sad     100
```

etc.

However, when I stick the JSON object into a dataframe I always end up with some variation of:

[image: example output]

Where the "scores" column is a list.  I've searched long and hard for an example, but can't figure out how to unpack the list into my desired format.

Suggestions?

Comment: In addition to my answer, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160134/flatten-a-column-with-value-of-type-list-while-duplicating-the-other-columns-va) seems like it might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to make a dataframe for each entry in your list, then concatenate them:

```
>>> pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in data])
```

This seems wasteful, though, since you're allocating a block of memory for each entry just to concatenate them in the end. Alternatively, you might define a generator:

```
def iter_data(data):
    for entry in data:
        for score in entry['scores']:
            yield entry['mood'], entry['id'], score
```

Such that

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(iter_data(data))

    id   mood  scores
0  abc  happy      10
1  abc  happy      15
2  abc  happy      20
0  def  happy     103
1  def  happy     150
2  def  happy     200
0  ghi    sad       1
1  ghi    sad      15
2  ghi    sad      20
3  ghi    sad      45
4  ghi    sad     600
5  ghi    sad    1400
0  jkl    sad      10
1  jkl    sad     100
2  jkl    sad    1000
3  jkl    sad   10000
```