# Pandas: find most frequent values in columns of lists

Tags: pandas

```
    x    animal
0   5    [dog, cat]
1   6    [dog]
2   8    [elephant]
```

I have dataframe like this. How can i find most frequent animals contained in all lists of column.

Method value_counts() consider list as one element and i can't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something along these lines?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [5,6,8], 'animal' : [['dog', 'cat'], ['elephant'], ['dog']]})
x = sum(df.animal, [])
#x
#Out[15]: ['dog', 'cat', 'elephant', 'dog']

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(x)
c.most_common(1)
#Out[17]: [('dog', 2)]
```

Comment: does it serve the purpose? @Alex Zaitsev

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a step back and redefine your data structure? Pandas is more suited if your dataframe is "flat".

Instead of:

```
    x    animal
0   5    [dog, cat]
1   6    [dog]
2   8    [elephant]
```

Do:

```
    x    animal
0   5    dog
1   5    cat
2   6    dog
3   8    elephant
```

Now you can count easily with `len(df[df['animal'] == 'dog'])` as well as many other Pandas things!

To flatten your dataframe, reference this answer:
[Flatten a column with value of type list while duplicating the other column's value accordingly in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160134/flatten-a-column-with-value-of-type-list-while-duplicating-the-other-columns-va)