# How to replicate data and replace values in one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe such as this:

```
samples  countries                 color   cost
a        US, UK, France, Germany   white   1.2
b        France, Germany           red     2.0
c        US                        blue    2.5
```

I would like to replicate data for each country (whenever there is a comma), so that it becomes:

```
samples  countries    color   cost
a        US           white   1.2
a        UK           white   1.2
a        France       white   1.2
a        Germany      white   1.2
b        France       red     2.0
b        Germany      red     2.0
c        US           blue    2.5
```

In other words, I just want the row to be replicated whenever there are multiple countries, while keeping values in other columns the same.

How can I do that with Pandas?
Thanks!

Comment: hope this link will help, same question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160134/flatten-a-column-with-value-of-type-list-while-duplicating-the-other-columns-va

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a chained operation:

First split the countries and stack them to rows, then join it back to the df, drop the old countries column and use the new countries column.

```
(
    df[df.columns.drop('countries')].join(df.countries.str.split(',')
                                            .apply(pd.Series).stack()
                                            .reset_index(1,drop=True)
                                            .to_frame()
                                            .rename(columns={0:'countries'}))
)
Out[67]: 
  samples  color cost countries
0       a  white  1.2        US
0       a  white  1.2        UK
0       a  white  1.2    France
0       a  white  1.2   Germany
1       b    red  2.0    France
1       b    red  2.0   Germany
2       c   blue  2.5        US
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `list`s, then get [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for `length`.

Then create new `DataFrame` by `constructor` with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). Last change order of columns by [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) and last create unique index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True`:

```
#columns for repeat
cols = ['samples','color','cost']
splitted = df['countries'].str.split(',')
lens = splitted.str.len()

df = pd.DataFrame({x:np.repeat(df[x], lens) for x in cols}) \
       .assign(countries=np.concatenate(splitted)) \
       .reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1) \
       .reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
  samples countries  color  cost
0       a        US  white   1.2
1       a        UK  white   1.2
2       a    France  white   1.2
3       a   Germany  white   1.2
4       b    France    red   2.0
5       b   Germany    red   2.0
6       c        US   blue   2.5
```